# Cannot connect to network

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a problem:

I am on Debian. I configured my nic with a static ip (192.168.1.56).

When I try to connect to a network, initially with ifconfig eth2 I get (correctly):

```
eth2 inet addr:192.168.1.56 .... 
inet6 addr: fe80:221:ff:fe96:4598/64
```

but after a few seconds the 192.168.1.56 disappears and after some other seconds disappears the inet6 address too. 
When I press in the nm-applet it requires me the password but in the meantime it try to connect.

At uni, the connection is a DHCP one. It works for the first few seconds but after it doesn't.

Any possible solution?

Here it is the relevant part of the syslog: (static ip configuration)
http://pastebin.com/u3BPAsda

Comment: You should be using `ip` instead of `ifconfig`, the latter has numerous known and unfixed problems.

Comment: uhm ok...I understand

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual command(s) you use to configure the NIC.  Are you using NetworkManager or command-line stuff with iwconfig or iw or what?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Debian user, but looking at the logs, eth2 is your wireless NIC and it's connecting to a wireless access point then waiting unsuccessfully for a DHCP assigned address. First of all this conflicts with your comment about setting a fixed IP and so some config info would be nice as CarlF said. Second although you are connecting to an access point this does not guarantee that the (WPA) key you are supplying is correct and that you have full authentication so do check the key you are using.